# What is [0] used for when reading dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Im trying to understand the purpose of [0] in this

```
        following_list.append(following["string_list_data"][0]["value"])
    for followers in data2["relationships_followers"]:
        followers_list.append(followers["string_list_data"][0]["value"])
    final_list = list(set(following_list) - set(followers_list))
   return final_list



{
  "relationships_following": [
    {
       "title": "",
       "media_list_data": [
    
      ],
         "string_list_data": [
        {
          "href": "foo",
           "value": "foo",
         "timestamp": foo
        }
      ]
    },
    {
  "title": "",
  "media_list_data": [
    
  ],
  "string_list_data": [
    {
      "href": "foo",
      "value": "foo",
      "timestamp": foo
    }
  ]
},
```

I am trying to get the values  of "value". What is [0] specifying? I know what the other ones do but not sure what [0] does.

Comment: The value for key `'string_list_data'` is a [one-element] list and [0] is access the element at index 0

Comment: @buran index 0 in relation to what keys? To me it looks like "value" which is what I'm trying to get is at index 1 (after href). Is href, value, timestamp, all accessed thru index 0? and then "value" is specifyed afterwards

Answer (score 1):

I advise you, when you have a question, to reproduce the problem in a separate file.
It helps a lot to understand

You may wonder what [0] is used for after the name of a list.

```py
example = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(example[0])
```

output

```
1
```

This is the first item in the list.

In the same way with a simple example

```py
for i in range(len(example)):
    print(f'example[{i}] = {example[i]}')
```

output

```
example[0] = 1
example[1] = 2
example[2] = 3
example[3] = 4
example[4] = 5
```

The first element is at index 0, the second at index 1, etc...

Comment: index 0 in relation to what keys? To me it looks like "value" which is what I'm trying to get is at index 1 (after href)

Comment: or does href, value, and timestamp all have the ability to be accessed at index 0

Comment: `random_list[0]` allows you to access the item in the first position of the list. In your example `followers["string_list_data"]` is a list composed of a single dictionary. Write `followers["string_list_data"][0]` allows you to access the first (and only in your example) element of this list which is the dictionary with the keys href, value, and timestamp.